# How to make a SweetAlert appear when joining my web?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I'm using SweetAlert and it's working fine in my page with this button:

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick='swal("Message", "This is a message")'>Title</button>
```

But I want the message to popup when somebody enter the page without having to press a button.

What do I have to do?

Thanks

Comment: what does your swal() function do?

Comment: What is the meaning of "joins the page" ?

Comment: Make this alert appear: https://prnt.sc/fj3n1q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
     swal("Message", "This is a message");
 }
</script>
```

You can try include this to your html document! Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        swal("Message", "This is a message");
    });
</script>
```